# python Flask resize image before upload to S3

Tags: javascript, flask, amazon-s3, python-imaging-library, form-data

I would like to resize a file image before uploading to S3, I'm using Flask, Pillow and FormData(). The idea is to upload a file from the frontend by the client in any size and my flask app will resize this file with a maximum with 500px and maximum height 1000px and then upload to my S3 bucket. My issue is when I use pillow to resize and try to upload to s3 won't work. Is someone have an idea how to do that? thank you.

my HTML and Javascript fetch post looks like this:

```
    <label for="reFile">Upload one File and resize it</label>
    </br>
    <input id="fileResize" type="file" name="reFile" accept="image/*">
    </br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="submitResize()" >Upload</button>

<script>
   const inputR = document.getElementById('fileResize');

    const submitResize = () => {
        resizeOne(inputR.files[0])
    };

    const resizeOne = (file) => {

        let fdR = new FormData();
        fdR.append('fileToResize', file);
        console.log(Array.from(fdR));

        fetch('https://samir-upload.herokuapp.com/resize', {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: fdR
        })
        .then(
            response => response.json()
        ).then(
            success => console.log(success)
        ).catch(
            error => console.log(error)
        );
    };
</script>
```

my flask application look like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, send_file
from flask_cors import CORS
from utils import APIException
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from helpers import *
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO  

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object("config")

CORS(app)


@app.route("/resize", methods=['PUT'])
def resize_uploaded_img():

    file = request.files['fileToResize']
    
    in_mem_file = BytesIO(file.read())
    image = Image.open(in_mem_file)
    image.thumbnail((500, 1000))
    in_mem_file = BytesIO()
    image.save(in_mem_file, format=image.format, filename=file.filename)
    file = in_mem_file

    output = upload_file_to_s3(file, app.config["S3_BUCKET"])
    return jsonify({
            'received': 'uploaded successfuly',
            'msg': str(output)
        })
```

my function upload_file_to_s3() is inside the helpers.py file and look like that:

```
def upload_file_to_s3(file, bucket_name, acl="public-read"):

    try:
        s3.upload_fileobj(
            file,
            bucket_name,
            file.filename,
            ExtraArgs={
                "ACL": acl,
                "ContentType": file.content_type
            }
        )

    except Exception as e:
        print("Something Happened: ", e)
        return e

    return "{}{}".format('http://{}.s3.amazonaws.com/'.format(S3_BUCKET), file.filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here the solution I found. It's working for me, I hope it will help someone else.

```
@app.route("/resize", methods=['PUT'])
def resize_uploaded_img():

    files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
    firstname = request.form['userName']
    lastname = request.form['userLast']

    if not files:
        raise APIException("You need to specify the request body as a json object", status_code=400)
    
    else:

        jobDone = []

        for file in files:

            if file.filename == "":
                return jsonify({
                        'received': 'nope its empty',
                        'msg': 'Please select a file'
                    })

            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                myFileName = secure_filename(file.filename)

                myType = file.content_type

                # myClientFolder = "clientFolder"
                myClientFolder = "activities/air"

                in_mem_file = BytesIO(file.read())
                image = Image.open(in_mem_file)
                image.thumbnail((600, 1000))
                in_mem_file = BytesIO()
                image.save(in_mem_file, format="PNG")
                in_mem_file.seek(0)

                output = upload_file_to_s3(in_mem_file, app.config["S3_BUCKET"], myClientFolder, myFileName, myType)

                jobDone.append(str(output))
                
            else:
                return jsonify({
                        'received': 'upload failed',
                        'msg': 'not upoladed, something is wrong!'
                    })

        return jsonify({
                'received': 'uploaded successfuly',
                'msg': jobDone,
                'first name': firstname,
                'last name': lastname
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to rewind the buffer after saving:

```
    # ...
    in_mem_file = BytesIO()
    image.save(in_mem_file, format=image.format, filename=file.filename)
    in_mem_file.seek(0)

    output = upload_file_to_s3(in_mem_file, app.config["S3_BUCKET"])
    # ...
```

Comment: I tried your solution, I have an error: Something Happened:  '_io.BytesIO' object has no attribute 'filename'

Comment: @samir I noticed in your original code you set `file = in_mem_file`.  This sounds like you've done something like that again.  I would use a different variable name for this because `file` is something else earlier in your function.  Re-using this could lead to confusion, which could have raised this exception.